# Intellij: Multi maven project beans

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project in Intellij 13 organized with the following structure:

```
main project
 - pom.xml
module 1
 - pom.xml
module 2
 - pom.xml
```

I added "module 1" and "module 2" to the "main project" by using "Add maven projects"

In the "main project" pom.xml I added the dependencies to the module 1 and module 2 like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>module1</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>module2</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, "main project" cannot see the beans of module1 and module2. Any idea what could be missing ?

Answer (score 0):

main project must be packaging pom and have modules element with the others.
Or add a main pom
sample here http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/indexer/trunk/

Comment: What do you mean for "Or add main pom sample here" ?

The project that you are linking are packaging the modules inside the main project. Is it possible to do it without packaging the modules inside the main project ?

Comment: not really. Just have a root pom which list various modules. So in your case it looks you simply need a top pom

Answer (score 0):

In your parent project POM...

```
<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
</modules>
```

And your folder structure should look something like this...

```
parent/proj/folder
 - pom.xml
parent/proj/folder/child1
 - pom.xml
parent/proj/folder/child2
 - pom.xml
```

**EDIT:**

Also, in case you didn't know, in your parent pom you declare all the versions of your dependencies, but when you include them in you child poms you **shouldn't** include the versions